# Read each character from EEPROM to string

Tags: c, embedded

I'm using char with pointer for create a string. So when i want to save my string in EEPROM, I'm using this code below.

```
char *Password= "1234";
int i = 0;

for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    DataEEWrite(i, *Password); 
    Password++;
}
```

This code works fine. How can i do the same for reading each `byte(char)` from `EEPROM` and creating a `string`? example i tried this but it didn't worked.

```
char *Password;
int i = 0;

for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
   Password[i] = DataEERead(i);

Password.Value[4] = '\0';
```

I'm getting an *uknown character* in output.

Comment: How do you declare `Password` in the read version?

Comment: Password it's declared as variable in top of my sourcefile.

Comment: If the definition of `Password` is what you show, then your code should not build, much less run and give you unexpected results. Or are you asking about the compiler error message (which you need to show us in full and complete)?

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I meant, show us how you've declared it, like you did for the writing block of code as it is important information that your question lacks.

Comment: I fixed it in my question

Comment: You should allocate memory to `Password` before trying to write to it.

Comment: You have to allocate `Password`, e.g. with malloc or a static array `char Password [5]`

Comment: You still haven't told us *who* tells you "unknown character"! If you're asking about the build error you should get with the code you show, then *say* so, and include the copy-pasted (as text) output from the build, in full and complete. If you get "unknown character" from somewhere else, you need to tell you from where, and preferably by showing us some code that actually builds.

Comment: you can use `strdup()`  to allocated the string, example `char *Password= strdup("lala");` make sure free this when you no longer need Password.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've declared `Password` isn't correct.

```
char *Password;
```

This is a pointer to some random place in memory, which you're not specifying anywhere in your code so you'll get undefined behaviour. You you can either assign it some allocated memory using `malloc()` or better for this simple example just use an array instead like this:

```
char Password[10];
```

If you were to use `malloc()` you would do it like this:

```
char *Password;
Password=malloc(10);
```

and when you're done with the memory you have to remember to free it.

```
free(Password);
```

To copy a string you use `strcpy`, which works with either option I've specified

```
strcpy(Password,"1234");
```

Comment: how can i use malloc to it? Or how can i give a quick value in char array? Like Password="1234";

Comment: Bit long to answer in comments, so I've expanded upon my answer

Comment: and how can i add each epprom byte which i will read? in password?

Comment: Is the way you're already doing not working? If it isn't, I have no idea - the only obvious problem with your code was how you were declaring `Password`

Comment: The OP was trying to store data in EEPROM, so this answer is completely wrong and misguiding. I would delete it.

Comment: @Lundin the question is about **reading** data from an EEPROM and storing it in a string. The OP wasn't initialising their `char *` so my answer explains what they were doing wrong and ways to fix it

Comment: "So when i want to save my string in EEPROM" followed by DataEEWrite sounds like they want to write to EEPROM. The first problem is that they are passing `*Password` to the function. Then of course you can't read into a non-allocated pointer either. Many fundamental bugs but the core of the question is about the API to these functions, whatever that's taken from.